# What is the most efficient way to create an https endpoint for existing Teams chatbot (python)?

Tags: python, azure, microsoft-teams, azure-bot-service

I've recently got a Teams chatbot working. The chatbot is written in Python and is based on code samples provided on the Microsoft Bot Builder GitHub (link below). As suggested in the code samples, I started off with using ngrok for testing. So the setup currently is like this:

1. When someone sends a message to the Bot, the message is routed to Azure Bot Service.
2. Asure Bot Service is configured to send traffic to an AWS EC2 instance which has ngrok running along with the python app. Ngrok endpoint: https://xyz.ngrok.io.
3. Python app on the EC2 instance responds back to the user (python app > ngrok > Azure Bot Service > Microsoft Teams).

The above setup works well but now I'd like to remove the ngrok intermediary. When I realize that Azure Bot Service only allows https endpoint and that my ngrok was doing the ssl. Looks like the code samples provided was from before Azure made it mandatory for Bot Service to only use https endpoint. Could anyone please advise what's the best way to move forward in my situation? I understand that re-architecture using api gateway/lambda would make it easier but I'd like to keep the current architecture for now. Is my only option to create certificates (which is new to me)? Appreciate any guidance here.

`https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/python/02.echo-bot`

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely remove ngrok, and it cetainly should be removed - it's only meant for local workstation development, and one of the main reasons is to support SSSL/TLS as httpS is -required- for bots. You'll need to spend some time figuring out how to get certificates working on your EC2, as a result, but it's probably really good experience as httpS is mandated for various things these days. Also, although I don't have any personal experience with EC2, these days I can't imagine it's hard to add certificates.